# What's the difference between importing a module inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` or outside with OpenMPI?

Tags: python, openmpi

I have two executable Python3 scripts that look like the following.

**script1**:

```py
#/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from mymodule import launch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(launch())
```

and

**script2**:

```py
#/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from mymodule import launch
    sys.exit(launch())
```

My understanding of CPython is that these two scripts should work identically.

However, if I try to run the `./script1` script using OpenMPI's `mpirun` like so:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./script1
```

it fails (on Debian linux) with the following errors:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  getting local rank failed
  --> Returned value No permission (-17) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_init failed
  --> Returned value No permission (-17) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "No permission" (-17) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[3018108860e1:05983] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

But if I run:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./script2
```

it runs without error.

I ***wish*** that I could give you a self-contained, short example of the `mymodule` module and the `go` function that reproduces this error.  I have tried to reduce my large production code to something small that reproduces the problem, but every time I try to trim down the production code to something small, the error is not reproducible.  So, that said, I am *not* asking you all to tell me where my bug is.

Instead, I am wondering if any of you have *any ideas* as to why the two launch scripts *might* behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard indicates that it's not used by any other code in the module. That is, if you import the module as a library to some other script, it'll work as intended without that import.

Some modules can take a long time to import so it is good practice to avoid importing them unless it's necessary.

Comment: Thank you @kindal for your reply.  I think I understand what you are indicating, but my understanding of this particular use case is that both scripts (importing the module under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard or not) should yield the same results if executed from the command-line.  So, I still don't understand why they even *could* yield different results.

Comment: The code under the guard uses the imported library. For example, it might use `argparse`  to parse the command line args preparatory to calling the other functions. If imported to some other script, it doesn't to do that and so doesn't need `argparse`.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks, @kindal, but that still doesn't explain why the two examples above behave differently when executed from the command line.  In both cases, the contents of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block *will be executed*.  Therefore, the executed lines in both scripts are the same.  The only difference is that the import statement is happening inside or outside the scope of the `if`-block, but I can't see why that would change behavior.